# JQuery Ajax call working but not native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two AJAX calls, one in native JavaScript and another with JQuery, which call a PHP Script. The JQuery one is working, but the JavaScript one not. Here goes the code:

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Tests/index.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {'Id': "2"}
});
```

Native JavaScript:

```
var Data = {Id: "2"};
XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(XHR.responseText);
    }
}
XHR.open("POST", "/Tests/index.php", true);
XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
XHR.send(JSON.stringify(Data));
```

PHP Script:

```
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

The one with JQuery returns `2`, but the JavaScript one, doesn't return anything. All the data is seen through the console of the web browser.

Comment: Why do you stringify again?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var Data = {"Id": "2"};
 var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();    // declared XHR var

 XHR.open("POST", "/Tests/index.php", true);
 XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

 XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     console.log(XHR.responseText);
   }
 }
XHR.send(Data);   // sending data without converting to string
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Keeps without getting the data. Well, using php://input i got the data, but using $_POST not. Any idea?

Comment: check this link:  http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/

Comment: Not this... I don't know.

Comment: Try sending synchronous calls then instead of async call